# How to give opacity for div when it is set Overflow=visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `1 div` and `1 image` tag , one upon the other. `Div` is smaller than `image`.
I have set `overflow=visible` for `div`. My question is that, when I insert an image to image tag, the content which is overflowed through div should be `opacity=0.5` like this.

[image: i want my div look like this]

for me it shows like this.. any help

```html
<div style="border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; height: 5cm; width: 8cm;top: 20px; left: 20px; position: relative;  overflow: visible;" id="divimg">
  <img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="displayimg" style="height: 7cm; width: 10cm;" />
</div>
```

Comment: if i set hidden, it will hide, but i want it to be visible and that visible content should be opacity

Comment: yes sorry, I didn't read properly your problem, I've deleted my comment anyway lol

Comment: So basically this is kind of image cropping functionality?

Comment: not like cropping, i am dragging and resizing, but whatever, the visible should be opacity like that image :)

Comment: Like **[this](http://codecanyon.net/item/html-5-upload-image-ratio-with-drag-and-drop/full_screen_preview/8712634?ref=jqueryrain)** Just look at functionality!

Comment: this is good, but how to implement it here ?

Comment: So what's the exact requirement? You are uploading the image or it will be always there??

Comment: i am uploading the image

Comment: So that's it right! You can easily implement that plugin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the demo for your requirement.

```css
.outter_div{width:400px; height: 200px;position: relative;}
.outter_div:after{content:"";border:50px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.5);position: absolute; top: 0;width: 300px;height: 100px;}
img{width: 100%;position:}
```

```html
 <div class="outter_div">
       <img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg"/>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sasikumar3/anx55xuj/)

Comment: This is good but, using position absolute makes you not able to place it wherever u like on the webpage, does it? :/

Comment: yea, i am trying to apply it for panel , so that it will fixed, beacause i am dragging and resizing my image :) , Thank u, let me try ..

Comment: we can use it anywhere as normal div. I have used position absolute only for inner div so it would not affect default image positioning.

Comment: @Sasikumar, can i add this class=outerdiv , to panel, will that outer_div:after will effect ?

Comment: If you want to replace outer_div class you should change class name in outer_div:after selector.

Answer (score 2):

If you can change HTML to something like this:

```
<div id="holder">
  <div id="overlay">          
  <img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="displayimg"  />

    </div>    
    <div id="box"></box>  

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#holder {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;

}

#overlay {
    width:500px;
    height:250px;
    opacity:0.5;

}
#displayimg {

    width:500px;
    height:250px;

}
#box {
    width:250px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:black;
     position:absolute;
    left:200px;
    top:70px;
    overflow:hidden;

}
#box #ima {

    position:absolute;
     width:500px;
    height:250px;
    display:block;
}
```

And little JQuery magic:

```
$('#box').append('<img src="https://stepupandlive.files.wordpress.com/2014/09/3d-animated-frog-image.jpg" id="ima"  /> ');

$('#ima').offset($('#holder').offset());

$( "#box" ).draggable();

  $( "#box" ).draggable({

      drag: function() {
      $('#ima').offset($('#holder').offset());
      }

    });
```

Since you have mentioned dragging, i have imported JQuery UI in fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/y3c41d10/1/

For resizing, you will have to do some calculations, but it is doable, i hope...

Comment: i have draggable and resizable code :), but i am dragging image itself, in ur code u are dragging div right ?, but code is nice, that box acts like mirror

Comment: Well, in that case, task is even easier: http://jsfiddle.net/y3c41d10/3/  You just drag img  holder div (its position is relative, so no need for additional calculations).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I came up with:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="sub">This is a text</div>
    </div>
</div>


.main {
    background-image:url(http://lorempixel.com/g/200/200/);
    position: relative;
}
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.sub {
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px;
    border: solid 30px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    color:white;
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tm51Lrgc/)

Comment: i want it for src, and i am resizing it.

Comment: for src? can you please give more details?

Comment: i am using image tag, i want to add image to src of image tag :(

Comment: The above example uses border-width and border-color for that effect. Parent div has the image as background image, and the child div uses the border to cover up the area. Since teh border is made transparent, it gives u that effect. In your case, an `img` tag cannot have a child element, so i dnt think it cant be done with an img tag :(

Comment: yea bro :( , i cannot add div inside image , anyways thank you.